# Issue while storing more than 1 Item into Mysql from Scrapy

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

So, I have this Issue which is driving me crazy, I'm trying to store scraped Items into MySQL via Pipelines but I am not able to do it.

If I store only 1 item, I can do it, but the second I add the second Item I get this weird error.

```
Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '), 1)' at line 2
```

So I get the error above and my code in pipelines.py is:

```
class DropToDb(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="root", db="Test")
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        try:
            self.cursor.execute("""
                          INSERT INTO Main (url, domain_id)
                          VALUES (%s, %s)
                    """, (item['url'], item['domain_id']))

            self.conn.commit()


        except MySQLdb.Error, e:
            print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])

        return item
```

and if I remove one table and Item than it works great, like below.

```
class DropToDb(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="root", db="Test")
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        try:
            self.cursor.execute("""
                          INSERT INTO Main (url)
                          VALUES (%s)
                    """, (item['url']))

            self.conn.commit()


        except MySQLdb.Error, e:
            print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])

        return item
```

My Scrapy file looks like:

```
if datematch:
    item['link_title'] = ogtitle
    item['link_description'] = response.xpath('//meta[@property="og:description"]/@content').extract()
    item['link_locale'] = response.xpath('//meta[@property="og:locale"]/@content').extract(),
    yield item
```

There are more items above but I just wanted example.

Can someone please help me get out of this ?

My Spider File:

```
import scrapy
import MySQLdb
from MySQLdb.cursors import SSCursor
from scrapy.http import Request
import re
from Maintoo.items import MaintooSpider2Item
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
import datetime
class Maintoospider2Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "MaintooSpider2"

    #start_urls = readdomainsfromdb()

    def start_requests(self):
        for domain_id, url, id_sitemap_links in readdomainsfromdb():
            yield Request(
                url,
                callback=self.parse,
                meta={
                    'domain_id': domain_id,
                    'id_sitemap_links': id_sitemap_links
                },
                errback=self.error
            )

    def error(self):
        pass

    def parse(self, response):
        domainid = response.meta['domain_id']
        id_sitemap_links = response.meta['id_sitemap_links']
        #updateid(id_sitemap_links)
        ogtitle = response.xpath('//meta[@property="og:title"]/@content').extract()
        isporn = response.xpath('//meta[@content="RTA-5042-1996-1400-1577-RTA"]').extract()
        datematch = re.findall(r'(content="2015|2016")', response.body, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
        item = MaintooSpider2Item()
        if '/tag/' in response.url:
            raise DropItem
        if isporn:
            updateporn(domainid)
            raise DropItem

        if datematch:
            item['link_title'] = ogtitle
            item['link_description'] = response.xpath('//meta[@property="og:description"]/@content').extract()
            item['link_locale'] = response.xpath('//meta[@property="og:locale"]/@content').extract()
            item['link_type'] = response.xpath('//meta[@property="og:type"]/@content').extract()
            item['link_url'] = response.xpath('//meta[@property="og:url"]/@content').extract()
            item['link_site_name'] = response.xpath('//meta[@property="og:site_name"]/@content').extract()
            item['link_article_tag'] = response.xpath('//meta[@property="article:tag"]/@content').extract()
            item['link_article_section'] = response.xpath('//meta[@property="article:section"]/@content').extract()
            item['link_article_published_time'] = response.xpath('//meta[@property="article:published_time"]/@content').extract()
            item['link_meta_keywords'] = response.xpath('//meta[@name="keywords"]/@content').extract()
            item['link_publisher'] = response.xpath('//meta[@property="article:publisher"]/@content').extract()
            item['link_article_author'] = response.xpath('//meta[@property="article:author"]/@content').extract()
            item['link_twitter_card'] = response.xpath('//meta[@name="twitter:card"]/@content').extract()
            item['link_twitter_description'] = response.xpath('//meta[@name="twitter:description"]/@content').extract()
            item['link_twitter_title'] = response.xpath('//meta[@name="twitter:title"]/@content').extract()
            item['link_twitter_image'] = response.xpath('//meta[@name="twitter:image"]/@content').extract()
            item['link_facebook_app_id'] = response.xpath('//meta[@property="fb:app_id"]/@content').extract()
            item['link_facebook_page_admins'] = response.xpath('//meta[@property="fb:admins"]/@content').extract()
            item['link_rss'] = response.xpath('//meta[@rel="alternate"]/@href').extract()
            item['link_twitter_image_source'] = response.xpath('//meta[@name="twitter:image:src"]/@content').extract()
            item['link_twitter_site'] = response.xpath('//meta[@name="twitter:site"]/@content').extract()
            item['link_twitter_url'] = response.xpath('//meta[@name="twitter:url"]/@content').extract()
            item['link_twitter_creator'] = response.xpath('//meta[@name="twitter:creator"]/@content').extract()
            item['link_apple_app'] = response.xpath('//meta[@name="apple-itunes-app"]/@content').extract()
            item['link_facebook_video'] = response.xpath('//meta[@property="og:video"]/@content').extract()
            item['link_facebook_page_id'] = response.xpath('//meta[@name="fb:page_id"]/@content').extract()
            item['link_id'] = response.xpath('//link[@rel="publisher"]/@href').extract()
            item['link_image'] = response.xpath('//meta[@property="og:image"]/@content').extract()
            item['url'] = response.url
            item['domain_id'] = domainid
            item['crawled_date'] = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
            yield item
```

My new Pipelines file:

```
class dropifdescription(object):

    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        # to test if only "job_id" is empty,
        # change to:
        # if not(item["job_id"]):
        if not(item["link_title"]):
            raise DropItem()
        else:
            return item

class DropToDb(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="root", db="Maintoo",  charset="utf8", use_unicode=True)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        try:
            self.cursor.execute("""
                              INSERT INTO Main (url, domain_id, link_title) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""", (item['url'], item['domain_id'], item['link_title']))

            self.conn.commit()


        except MySQLdb.Error, e:
            print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])

        return item
```

My Settings File:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'Maintoo.pipelines.dropifdescription': 200,
    'Maintoo.pipelines.DropToDb': 300,
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is coming from inside of your spider.

> `item['link_locale'] = response.xpath('//meta[@property="og:locale"]/@content').extract(),`

See this `,` at the end - this is making your `item['link_locale']` a tuple, which eventually breaks your SQL query. Remove the comma.

And, aside from that, you should be using [`extract_first()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#id1) as opposed to using regular `extract()` to extract single values instead of lists.

Comment: your answer resolved me the problem for 2 item, once I added another one the problem is still the same. def process_item(self, item, spider):
        try:
            self.cursor.execute("""
                              INSERT INTO Main (url, domain_id, link_title)
                              VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""",
                                (item['url'],
                                 item['domain_id'],
                                 item['link_title']
                                 ))

            self.conn.commit()
What is going on with my code... where is the problem now ?

Comment: @BesnikHajredini could you post your complete spider (edit the question and paste it there)? Thanks.

Comment: I added the complete spiders file so far, and settings file... I hope you can help me out on this cuz I'm stuck :)

Comment: @BesnikHajredini okay, added a note about `extract_first()` vs `extract()` - check it out. Thanks.